# Selecting auto-populate dropdown in Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

Example:
http://phppot.com/demo/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/
Code:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Check Drop Down');
$I->amOnPage('http://phppot.com/demo/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/');
$I->see('Demo jQuery Dependent DropDown List - Countries and States');
$I->selectOption('country-list', '1');
$I->selectOption('state-list', '16');
```

I don't want to use `webdriver`, is there any possible way in Codeception or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to test Javascript code in PHP without using WebDriver.